# how to get the difference between 2 tables in 2 different schema's in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am using Oracle 11G.

I have a table called **Tickets** in the schema called '**tickets1**"
I have the same table structure in another schema called '**tickets2**'

I want to find out

1. What data is the same in both tables?
2. What data is different?

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tickets(
>     ticket_number NUMBER NOT NULL,    
>     first_name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
>     last_name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY(ticket_number)
> );
> ```

Comment: I am assume the relationship between primary and other column of data are parent/child. you can use select a.* , b* from tickets1, tickets2 where a.key=b.key to see the same

Comment: I am assume the relationship between primary and other column of data are parent/child. you can use select a.* from tickets1 minus select b.* from tickets2 to see the difference, if ticket1 dataset enclose ticket2 dataset

Comment: @scottyu can you post your comment as an answer so it can be accepted?

Comment: becuase the question is not clear, I only put in comment area, if you can clarify more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For same data, use `INTERSECT`

```
SELECT * FROM TICKETS1.TICKETS
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM TICKETS2.TICKETS
```

For difference of data, use `MINUS` and `UNION` as follows

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM TICKETS1.TICKETS
MINUS
SELECT * FROM TICKETS2.TICKETS)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM TICKETS2.TICKETS
MINUS
SELECT * FROM TICKETS1.TICKETS)
```